# JIT is incompatible with third party extensions that override. How to find a culprit?

Tags: php

I'm trying to enable JIT but getting error  `JIT is incompatible with third party extensions that override zend_execute_ex()`
Here is the list of all the extensions I have (`php -m`)

```
[PHP Modules]
blackfire
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
fileinfo
filter
ftp
hash
iconv
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mongodb
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_pgsql
pdo_sqlite
pgsql
Phar
posix
random
readline
redis
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
sodium
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
blackfire
```

How can I debug it further to find which extension conflict with JIT? I'm on php 8.2.4

Comment: okay, looks like it's blackfire, `Blackfire does not support the JIT option of PHP 8. Blackfire may actually crash if you enable this feature, therefore we do not recommend it. We’re working on compatibility when JIT is activated.`

Comment: That should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: For a start, try with a minimal configuration. For example, `php -n` will not load any default configfile. Then, bisect the modules you would regularly load to circle in on those that don't work.